# Cannot hit nginx from outside localhost

Tags: nginx, centos5

I am a newbie on nginx, what I am trying to do is setup nginx and be able to use it as my webserver.

The issue I am facing now is that when I try to access the IP or domain name that nginx is listening to I get 'The connection has timed out'. On the other hand if I ssh to my server and then do curl or wget on the same IP or domain I get a reply with what it suppose to print.

Basically I can hit nginx locally but not globally. Is there any permissions missing or should I use another user other than nginx in the configuration?

**I tried to disable apache server and run nginx and listen to all 80 still same issue exists**

My nginx settings is as follows :

```
#######################################################################
#
# This is the main Nginx configuration file.
#
# More information about the configuration options is available on
#   * the English wiki - http://wiki.nginx.org/Main
#   * the Russian documentation - http://sysoev.ru/nginx/
#
#######################################################################

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Module - directives that cover basic functionality
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Events Module
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpEventsModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

events {
    worker_connections  1024;


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# HTTP Core Module
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    #
    # The default server
    #
    server {
        listen       69.162.77.106:80;
        server_name  warstarz.com;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/warstarz.com/html/;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

       error_page  404              /404.html;
       location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that you are accessing it via a wrong URL.

The domain you refer to in your NGINX config resolves to

```
% dig warstarz.com +short
69.162.77.100
```

and thus doesn't match the IP address your server is listening on.

NMAP reports an Apache httpd listening on `69.162.77.106:80`.

Verify that NGINX is running and listening on the correct IP and Port with `ps` and `netstat`.

Comment: Yes you are right now I fixed that but still same issue exist. I changed mis-configured nginx and apache but still same issue any other suggestion. Thanks that was helpful

Comment: `warstarz.com` still resolves to `69.162.77.100`, so that definitely _is_ a problem. I emulated a request like this: `curl -v -H "Host: warstarz.com" http://69.162.77.106`, but this gets me a response from Apache. Does nginx actually start?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of fuero answer and I changed the IP am using to another one totally different I got it working, later I figured that the IP I am using is not in my IP tables I added it after but now up and running.

Thanks